# How to store an array of instances

Tags: java

I'm coding in Java, but most languages would do just fine.

Right now, I have an implementation like this:

I have an array that stores objects from a class.  The array's length is 10,000.

This is for a little project I working on.  Essentially, over time, any place in the array can be unused or have an object in it.  Objects can be created or destroyed at any moment.

What I was trying to figure out was the best way to store and recall them to minimize time for two steps:

1. Creating an object.  Cycling through the array until you find an open slot can be slow when lots of instances are near the front.
2. Drawing an object.  I have to cycle through the array constantly, and, based on the existence of an instance, retrieve and display information regarding it.

My current system uses a list of the Objects, as well as a list of Booleans.  When creating an object, I just cycle through till the first empty place in the array, then fill it, and to draw, I just go over the whole thing.

Granted, it isn't slow enough to make the project impossible, but I'd still like to know the most efficient method.

Comment: why don't you simply use a list?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, but I may be wrong. Actually, I am wrong, it sounds more like a list or a set.

Comment: Does the order of the instances matter?

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you need the array to allow "empty slots" in it. If you don't actually require that, then just use a List, which expands and contracts as necessary-- this is easier than you're used to if you're coming from, say, raw C.

Comment: Is an array the right data structure for storing these objects?  If you can talk a little about the rationale for the array or about the pattern of how the data is being accessed and/or stored in the array?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, I should have made that clear.  Essentially, the issue is that it's variable-length, in that any number of instances could be in it, and any instance could be removed at any moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is not to do this.  Use one of the [Java collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).  If you aren't going to be adding or removing things very often, maybe use a `ArrayList`.  If you are, then use a `LinkedList`.  And if you want to maintain a mapping to particular indices, you might consider e.g. a `TreeMap`.  These are all iterable.

Comment: That sounds good.  Thanks, I'm new to Java Datatypes, but I know what LinkedLists are, and I think it will work.

Answer (score 2):

What about using some sort of named-map construct instead of an array such as a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?
This will link your objects to a unique key and then you can just use .remove(key) to remove the object once its done.

No real iterations involved, just direct access.

Comment: That sounds good, but like I said, I have to iterate over all of them.  Would a HashMap work for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a second datastructure, a simple list of 'unused' locations in your array. When you remove an object, push either a reference to that array location or the index of that array location into your list. When you need to add an object, take the first item off your list. When the list is empty, then you get to scan your array as you do now, but when the list isn't empty, finding an unused element can be *very* quick. (You could keep a list of *all* unused places, which would remove the full-array search, but keeping a list of 10,000 unused items also seems excessive.)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a list where you could place the indexes of the empty spaces in the array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array, you could use a `HashSet` or even `HashMap` without worrying about open slots or the max capacity your array can hold. You also don't need to worry about adding duplicate objects in `HashSet` or `HashMap`. With `HashMap`, it allows you to get your object by whatever key you assigned to the object... makes your code looks cleaner without all the loopings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object[] and just keep around an index to the first open slot. Although, that's pretty much what an ArrayList does.

Also, be aware that iteration through an array of 10k items, is incredibly fast. I wouldn't be concerned about that time unless you have proven it to be an issue.